# Figuring out the Content of the Tuple before Loops were executed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently came across this question while doing an online course and I am a bit lost on why there is a 5 and 8 in the options which I have to rearrange. It would much appreciated if someone could help me solve this and explain why is it as such. As seen in the screenshot, it says "the first two have already been filled in for you". I have to rearrange 1, 8, 6, 5, 3, 9, 2, 0.

[image: Question Screenshot]

I tried understanding the code on my own.. But I've been stuck for ages.

Comment: The first five values printed out will be the values in the tuple at the even indices (starting at zero), i.e, 4 is the 0-index value in the `myTuple`, 8 is the 2-index value, 0 is the 4-index value, etc. The second five values are those at the odd indices (starting at 1), i.e., 7 is the 1-index value, 1 is the 3-index value, etc.

Comment: The answer is '4,7,8,1,0,3,6,2,9,5'

Answer (score 1):

The two while loops print the elements of your tuple.

For example `print(myTuple[1])` will print the second element of the tuple (since indices in python start with 0). So you have to figure out what the output of the program means.

To give you a hint, check what `i` is, i.e. which element is printed at which time. For example the second print (8) there `i=2`, therefore the third element in your tuple should be an 8.